# PHP - change internal function vars by external function

Tags: php, function, variables, internal

is it possible to change variables in a function by calling an external function? just found a topic her with the same question in javascript

as example I have the following function

```
function foo() {
    $bar = 50;
    var_dump($bar);
    foobar();
    var_dump($bar);
}

function foobar() {
    // change $bar to 40
    // all I have is the name of the var => "bar"
}
```

thank you for any suggestions

Comment: You could using globals but you really shouldn't. Just send the correct parameters to the function and have it return the values you need.

Comment: I don't think that I wanna do it over this way, thanky you anyway. I mean it is not that nice when I have like 13 variables or something.

Comment: Use arrays if you need to pass multiple variables. You would need to declare them global one-by-one in your functions anyway so putting them as arguments is actually shorter.

Comment: hmm that is quite dirty.. isn't it? I have still clean code now and won't using an array for all this variables.

Comment: jeroen's solution is quite standard if you want to pass multiple variables to the same function. There is nothing "dirty" about it. The alternative is quite ugly: passing 13 variables as individual parameters to the function.